# nodejs telegrafjs bot set webhook not polling

Tags: node.js, polling, telegraf

to clearbot.madeira.uz domain, these scripts are configured via nginx, the webhook via telegram webhook api is successful ("was set"), but my bot is not working, the Bot module in the code is working without problems in the .launch() system, I just want to use my bot via webHook i want

I don't know what to do, I looked at the telegraph documentation